# When a solid is melting how do the potential energy and kinetic energy of the particles in the solid change?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

When a solid is melting, does the kinectic energy and potential energy of the **particles** in the solid change? Will they remain the same or increase or decrease.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: My thoughts are, kinetic would increase while potential woud stay the same. But i'm not sure.

Comment: Does not a phase change generally occur at constant temperature?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: When ice melts at 1 atmosphere doesn't it occur at constant temperature (i.e., 0 C)?

Comment: Yes, oh so therefore kinetic energy is constant as there is no temperature change i see. What about potential energy?

Comment: There are only two types of internal (molecular) energy, kinetic and potential, the latter related to the separation of molecules. If the kinetic energy doesn't change what does?

Comment: The potential does not change?

Comment: Think again about what I just said.

Comment: So it changes because kinetic does not?

Comment: If kinetic doesn't change it must be potential energy increases. There are no other possibilities. All energy boils down to kinetic and. potential- which can be found in many forms. In this case heat added to the solid causes an increase in molecular separation (increase in potential energy) without an increase in molecular motion (increase in kinetic energy). Is it clear to you now?

Comment: Oh, understood . Thanks a lot for your time!